# Let $G$ be a noncyclic group of order $21$. How many Sylow-$3$ subgroup does $G$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a noncyclic group of order $21$. How many Sylow-$3$ subgroup does $G$ have?

Based on the 3rd Sylow theorem, we know a group of order $21$ must have either $1$ or $7$ Sylow $3$ subgroup. Now my text goes on to quote the second part of the following corollary which shows why the answer must be $1$.

> **Corollary $9.18$**
>
> Let $G$ be a group of order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes such that $p \gt q$.
> If $q \not \mid (p-1)$, then $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{pq}$
>
> **Proof:** By the Third Sylow Theorem, the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups must divide $|G|=pq$, and hence, must be one of $1$, $p$, $q$, or $pq$. However, the number must aslo be of the form $1 + pk$ for some integer $k$. Since $p \gt q$, we cannot have $q = 1 + pk$. Furthermore, both $p = 1 + pk$ and $pq = 1 + pk$ imply that $p \mid 1$, which is impossible. Therefore, there is exactly one Sylow $p$-subgroup $H$ of order $p$, which is normal by Corollary $9.16$. A similar argument (using the fact that $q \not \mid (p-1)$) shows that there is a unique Sylow $q$-subgroup $K$ of order $q$, which is also normal. Since $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of both $H$ and $K$, its order must divide both $|H| = p$ and $|K| = q$ by Lagrange's Theorem. Hence $H \cap K = \langle e \rangle$. Exercise $15$ shows that $G = HK$. Therefore, $G = H \times K$ by Theorem $9/3$. But $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $K \cong \mathbb{Q}_q$ by Theorem $8.7$. Consequently, by Lemma $9.8$, $G = H \times K \cong \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_q \cong \mathbb{Z}_{pq}$.

This corollary basically uses the second Sylow theorem and some results from internal direct products of subgroups. I read it a few times and I still don't know why the answer is $1$. I know the key point of the corollary is that if there is only one Sylow $3$ subgroup, then it is normal and there is also only $1$ Sylow $7$ subgroup (which means that is also normal) so their internal direct product is the entire group and by another theorem about internal products, our group is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_3 \times\Bbb Z_7$ which is cyclic which is a contradiction. But the thing here is that even if we have $7$ Sylow $3$ subgroup, the intersection with the Sylow $7$ subgroup is still just the identity so the direct product is still the entire group so we don't need the fact that the Sylow $3$ subgroup is normal to prove this result.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: It seems to me that you are done. You have proved that if there is one Sylow $3$-subgroup then $G$ is cyclic. So it follows immediately that if $G$ is not cyclic, then there are $7$ Sylow $3$-subgroups. What's the problem? (In fact there is such a group - i.e. a non-cyclic group with $7$ Sylow $3$-subgroups, but you don't need to know that to solve the problem.)

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't). In the future you should do the same so that future users will have an easier time finding this question ^_^. Also, would you please include what book you've found this in?

Comment: The proof you quote applies if $q\nmid(p-1)$  but $3|6$ so it does not apply.